# invoking a shell script for compiling a java code through php exec command

Tags: java, php, linux, bash, exec

I'm using a vps of CentOS. I've installed java onto it:

**java -version 

java version "1.8.0_65"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)**

If I was to compile a program from the shell using PuTTy or so I'm able to do so using a "javac"
However, I want to invoke a shell file ("compilerun.sh"),which accepts 2 parameters: 
 1. Filename for compilation(eg. Hello.java)
 2. Classname(eg. Hello)  
through a php file ("run.php") for a requirement.

The files look like this:

**run.php**:-

```
echo exec("./compilerun $compileFile $classname");

readfile('ErrorOP');
```

**compilerun.sh**:-

```
javac $1 >& ErrorOP;
java $2 >& ErrorOP;
```

**But, I'm getting output:**

"./compilerun.sh: line 1: javac: command not found "

Comment: This is all pretty complicated, but anyway... Your primary issue probably is that the executed php script does not have a valid `PATH` environment set, at least that does not hold the path to the `javac` executable. Have a try setting the path or use an absolute path to your executable.

Comment: how should I set PATH variable for php..?

Comment: Not for php, but for the account executing the script. You define such environment variables in the setup scripts executed when initializing a shell for a given account. If that is unfamiliar for you, then simply go with the "absolute path" solution I mentioned. Much easier.

Comment: These are the variables set:

Comment: root@vps [/usr/local/jdk/bin]# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/jdk
root@vps [/usr/local/jdk/bin]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin

Comment: And where is `javac`?

Comment: javac is there in /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_65/bin <br/> however, "jdk" is the symblic link to /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_65. But, it runs fine for shell and not for php..?? Why is it so..?

Comment: Sounds like that `$PATH` variable is not the one used inside the php script. I suggest you extend that php script to dump the current `$PATH` environment variable. And once more the question: _why don't you simply use an absolute path to the executable and all is fine? (`/usr/local/jdk/bin/javac ...`)...